# div.append not working in IE when debugger is closed

Tags: jquery

div.append not working in IE when debugger is closed. after send data to server loadpartialview is called to get latest and try to update in div named noticount. it does update in other browsers and IE when debugger is opened but do not do this when debugger is closed in IE.

- partial which calls after 5 seconds

  ```
  var count = 0;
  function loadPartialView() {
      var allIncident = null;

      $.ajax({

          url: "@Url.Action("LoadIncidentNotification", "AccidentOrDamage")",
          type: 'GET',
          async: false,
          success: function (result) {
              allIncident = $.parseJSON(result).allIncidents;
              if (allIncident.length > 0) {
                  count = allIncident.length;
                  //$('#notiCount').empty();
                  $('#notificationList').empty();
                  //$('#notiCount').append(allIncident.length);
                  $('#notiCount').html(allIncident.length);
              }
              else {
                  count = 0;
                  $('#notiCount').empty();
                  $('#notificationList').empty();
                  document.getElementById("overflow").style.overflowY = "unset";
                  $('#notificationList').empty();
                  $('#notificationList').append('<li>No New Notification</li>');
              }
              $.each(allIncident, function (k, v) {

                  $('#notificationList').append("<li> <a style='text-decoration: none;color: black;font-weight: normal !important; font-style:normal;' href='#' onclick='javascript:showSendClaimPopup1(" + v.Id + ",\"" + v.MobileNumber + "\",\"" + v.ClaimNumber + "\");'>Claim Request From " + v.Driver + "</a></li>");
              });
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- code for loading function after 5 seconds

  ```
  $(function () {
      loadPartialView();
      window.setInterval("loadPartialView()", 5000);
  });
  ```
- sends some data to server

  ```
   var SaveSendClaimClick1 = function () {
      if (!ClaimValidate1()) {
          return false;
      }
      var params = { 
              Id: $("#txtId1").val(), 
              ClaimNo: $("#txtClaimNo1").val() 
       };

      params = JSONStringify(params);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "@Url.Action("SaveSendClaim", "AccidentOrDamage")",
          data: params,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function (msg) {
              //debugger;

              if (msg != null) {
                  if (msg.id != null) {
                      if (msg.id == "-1") {
                          closePopup1($("#divSendClaimPopup1"), true);
                          jError(msg.msg, 'Error', function () {
                              //$('.mask1').fadeOut('slow');
                              //$('.mask').fadeOut('slow');
                          });
                      } else if (msg.id == "1") {
                          closePopup1($("#divSendClaimPopup1"), false);
                          jInformation(msg.msg, 'Information', function () {
                              //debugger;
                              //$('.mask1').fadeOut('slow');
                              //$('.mask').fadeOut('slow');
                          });
                          //reloadGrid();
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          error: function (e) {
              jError(e.responseText, 'Error', function () {
                  //$('.mask1').fadeOut('slow');
                  //$('.mask').fadeOut('slow');
              });
          }
      }); //    $.ajax({
  };
  ```

Comment: Which version of IE is giving you the problem? Also you might have an errant console.log(); somewhere in the code outside of this that is causing an issue, I am not completely familiar with joomla error and information messages but I bet those could be causing an issue as well.

Comment: system was using console.log but i have removed that already. cant control js like 'jquery.dataTables.js' or some other using it or not can I? IE11 is the version. thanks for the concern.

Comment: I can't really see a problem with this code block my guess you are getting some sort of console log or error somewhere ahead of this that is causing the problem.  This is just one of those issues that you have to look at the entire project and add break points to try to find where the issue is coming from.